# Django: Detailed and List View URLS - Call same function from views?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views

So basically i know i can call different functions based on urls from the urls.py in django.
Now what i want to know is, can i call the same function for two different urls:
Eg:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^v1/ttu/appliance/',views.get_appliances),
    url(r'^v1/ttu/appliance/(?P<appliance>[-.\w]+)$',views.get_appliances),
]
```

and my get_appliances in **views.py** is something like this:

```
def get_appliances(request, appliance):
    if appliance is None:
        #do something
    else:
        #do something else
```

is this possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can keep 2 urls like that,

you should use it like this

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^v1/ttu/appliance/$',views.get_appliances),
        url(r'^v1/ttu/appliance/(?P<appliance>[-.\w]+)/$',views.get_appliances),
    ]
```

and view function in views.py

```
def get_appliances(request, appliance=None):
    if appliance is None:
        #do something
    else:
        #do something else
```

Comment: Hi, I did try this out, but the problem is whenever i try accessing "v1/ttu/appliance/" url i get "Page not found (404), did not match any urls" error. But the "v1/ttu/appliance/xyz" works fine

Comment: sorry, yeah, you need to give another url, wait will update my answer

Comment: You can try with swapping the urls order.

Comment: @Exprator this works now. I was about to post the answer. Anyhow thank you :)

Comment: @AkshayValsa had to swap the order to make it work. Thank you